# Docker container with nestjs app exits without any error

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am trying to dockerize nestjs application. I have to use approach of our devops, so I can't give all details of configuration.
Scripts in package.json typical for any nestjs application.
I have Dockerfile.backend:

```
FROM some.registry.net/docker/node16 as builder
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --chown=app:app ./nestjs/nest-project .
RUN yarn install --non-interactive --production --frozen-lockfile

FROM some.registry.net/docker/node16 as serve
WORKDIR /opt/app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV APP_CONFIG=/opt/app/config/config.yaml
COPY --chown=app:app ./build/Procfile /opt/startup/Procfile
COPY --chown=app:app ./build/config.yaml ./config/config.yaml
COPY --chown=app:app --from=builder /opt/app/ ./
COPY --chown=app:app --from=builder /opt/app/node_modules ./node_modules
USER root
##RUN npm install pm2 -g
##RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm run build
CMD ["/opt/startup/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And I have docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/Dockerfile.backend
    command: npm run start
    ##volumes:
      ##- ./nestjs/nest-project:/app
      ##- /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 4001:4001
      - 9229:9229
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=4001
      - REACT_APP_PROD=0
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4001
      - FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:4000
      - APP_CONFIG=/opt/app/config/config.yaml


  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: npm start
    ##volumes:
      ##- ./frontend:/app
      ##- /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4001/backend
      - PORT=4000
      - REACT_APP_PROD=0
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
```

So the most interesting point lies in backend command part. I am able to start container only with `npm run start:dev` command. When I enter there `npm start` or `npm run start:prod`
container executes (I see in logs that nestjs app starts, successfully connects to database) and exits without any errors. I tried `node dist/main` and got the same result. I tried nodemon, with `nodemon dist/main` nodemon, even with verbose flag shows red line something like `app crashed...` and gives no more information. I tried pm2 with this command `pm2 --name nestjs start npm -- start` pm2 successfully starts and container exits without any information.
So far I see problem lies somewhere in my configuration, but I have no clue where to seek. Thanks in advance.